# Problems with Eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just begun learning Android developing.

Initially I followed the instructions at developer.android.com. I should mension that I also, had ADT before, bul a bit older version. I have updated SDK manager of first ADT and it does not work now, since plagins are not match. I deleted it at all and downloaded latest version of ADT 23.0.3. Also ubdated from SDK manager. 
Finally I created 'Hello world' application. But, on automatically generated code of my APP, almost all lines are underlined in red.

Could someone explain me why it is happening. And how can I solve this problem

Comment: did you define your build target of your project? (Right click on your project > properties > Android > Project Build targeT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have also face this type of problem at 4 July 2014 and there are many developers faced  this type of problem,Then I use Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker forum but I cant resolve this problem.At last I have use new eclipse with current Android SDK and it is working fine.

Comment: So I should Download again new ADT from developer.android.com and use its eclipse with my previous SDK? Am I understood you correct? @Ranjeet Kushwaha

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone explain me why it is happening. And how can I solve this
>   problem

**First**, Check the target build in   `Project > Properties > Android > Project Build Target`. It should be the latest one that you are using for your layout XML file elements.
Otherwise there will be no way for Eclipse to correctly generate the `R.java` file which will cause all the problems.

**My latest Project Build Target is - Google APIs API Level 19**

[image]

**Second**,

You need to do `Project -> Clean`.

This should, among others, regenerate your `R.java` file.

Also get rid of any `import android.R.*` statements and then do the clean up I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try Project->Clean.
You may have to let the project sit for a few minutes to clear up references and everything else. If that still doesn't work try restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Many, many people on this forum have experienced similar problems with the sdk download including myself. I have installed the sdk both on XP and recently Windows 8. If you followed the instructions carefully you should have the Java JDK installed prior to downloading and installing the SDK. Make sure that your PATH variable in your system environment variables points to the folder where the JDK resides, but do not delete or override your original OS PATH variable. Just add it before the OS PATH variable with a semicolon before the orginal path variables.
Also make sure that the JDK is in your main program files Java folder. Finally, if all else fails redownload the SDK from another browser. Hope this helps. If not try some of the many other solutions you can find on this forum.

Comment: Hi bro's. I tried to check your suggestion, an for several time was digging inside windows->preferences. If it is possible could you instruct me how to implement your suggestion. @blganesh101

Comment: You need to go to control panel then system then advanced system settings and then click on environment variables. Then you can click on the PATH variable and click edit and add the file address for your Java Development Kit. Just make sure that you do not delete or alter the already existing PATH variable because that could cause a problem in your OS. Just add your file location to the beginning of the PATH variable and put a semicolon before the other variables.